# How do I add another attribute in my Amazon SNS message email body?

Tags: amazon-sns

I need to add an attribute to the message notification which I get from SNS. The message body is like this.

```
{"Service":"Amazon S3","Event":"s3:TestEvent","Time":"2014-11-21T22:28:23.300Z","Bucket":"newbucket","RequestId":"AKJASKJDKALLASJ","HostId":"kasjdnkjabsaV/aab/xy/sadfadgfdsgfdsgdfs/+u8asdasasfdasdfadsfCc="}
```

However, I would like to add my custom parameter or attribute to this. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification format is generated by Amazon S3. It cannot be customized.

See:

- [Enabling Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/SettingBucketNotifications.html)
- [Event Message Structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html)